# How to use connection string stored in web.config to formulate MySQL connection query in ASP .NET Razor MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm successfully able to connect to my database with the following method, however I have a connection string stored in my web.config that I obviously would rather use than this way where the credentials are exposed in code. However I haven't found a good way to do this. WebMatrix gives me a fatal connection error of 18 and I don't know how else I can do  this off the top of my head.

[image: What I currently have]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the connection string from `Web.config` with something like this:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["someName"].ConnectionString;
```

which returns a string, just like `myBuilder.ConnectionString` does.  So you can use it directly in place of what you have:

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["someName"].ConnectionString;
MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
```

Comment: hey david. I tried that and I'm getting "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'
SocketException: No such host is known" on myconn.Open();

Comment: This is how it looks in the config.

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="jj_booking_system" connectionString="server=rds-booking-system.andtherestoftheendpoint.com,3306;database=jj_booking_system;uid=saydin;pwd=somepassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: @sushi7777: When you debug, have you confirmed that it's finding the right connection string from the config?  If the connection string is correct and it can't connect then, well, it can't connect.

Comment: server=rds-booking-system.andtherestoftheendpoint.com,3306;database=jj_booking_system;uid=saydin;pwd=somepassword is literally what is in the connString variable. Bear in mind the above screenshot works fine...

Comment: @sushi7777: In your original working version, what was the runtime value for `myBuilder.ConnectionString`?  Was it identical to the new runtime value?

Comment: no worries I fixed it - realised I was using the System.Data.SqlClient instead of MySql.Data.MySqlClient and just capitalised the variable names in the connection string. Don't quite understand why I have to use MySql instead of Sql though...

Comment: @sushi7777 Why don't you understand why you have to use MySqlClient instead of SqlClient? SqlClient is for connecting to Microsoft's SQL Server. MySqlClient is for connecting to MySQL.